# References in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

this may be a stupid question but when I add a reference to my project and set Copy Local to false (so it doesn't copy the dll to the working directory) I get this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bd319b19eaf3b43a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

All I want is to load the dlls from "(working directory)/dlls"
Is this even possible? And what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References simply aren't resolved relative to the working directory of the process - they're resolved relative to the assembly which is trying to load them (or from the GAC of course).

It's not clear *why* you want to do this, but basically you should make sure the DLL is available in the same location as the executable.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer!  But the reason why I want them in a separate folder is to make it look more "organized".

Comment: @Darkshadw: You can put them in a *subdirectory* of the executable, using the *private paths* feature of appplication configuration. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx - but that's *not* the same as "the working directory of the process".